# Creating new JSON in Python from subset of larger JSON

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to python and am trying to do the following in Google Cloud Functions

1) Call an API to return JSON weather data

2) Extract relevant pieces of the returned data and create a new simple JSON

3) Publish JSON to BigQuery table

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

weatherString = requests.get('https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/33.40/-83.42/observations.json?language=en-US&units=e', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass')

data=weatherString.json()

print("Hum",data['observation']['rh'])
print("Pressure",data['observation']['pressure'])
print("DewPt",data['observation']['dewPt'])
print("Temp",data['observation']['temp'])
```

This works to print the values from the keys but what I'm trying to do is create a new JSON object using these pairs.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by JSON object?

Comment: `data=weatherString.json()` deserializes JSON to regular python structures (lists, dicts and primitives). Do the reverse; make a valid python structure and serialize it as JSON.

Comment: Dustin's answer shows how to create a JSON dict. How do you plan to store this data in BigQuery? Do you plan to store the JSON data in a single column as a JSON string or do you plan to store each part (Pressure, Temp, etc.) as separate columns? In the latter case you do not need a JSON dict.

Comment: Thanks yall, I did mean dictionary.  (Clearly new to this....)

So this returns number values for rh, pressure, dewPt, and temp keys (from the observation "parent" key).  I want to take those values and build a new dictionary like this:

Hum:rh

Pressure:pressure

etc

Comment: @JohnHanley Pressure, Temp, etc are the keys and the values returned by the api call will be stored in another column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "JSON object" in Python -- what you're trying to create is a `dict`:

```
result = {
    "Hum": data['observation']['rh'],
    "Pressure": data['observation']['pressure'],
    "DewPt": data['observation']['dewPt'],
    "Temp": data['observation']['temp'],
}
```

This can then be serialized to a JSON string as follows:

```
json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: JSON - JavaScript Object Notation. I think this confuses some.

Comment: Thanks all of you, got my question answered and some extra knowledge, more than I hoped for!